# Avro Schema Evolution: Can't add or remove fields

Tags: java, avro

I'm currently trying to evolve my avro schema which should be no big deal according to the docs. However, when adding or removing a field Avro can't deserialize the bytes.

I'm using the following schema:

**AvroSchemas.avsc:**

```
[
  {
    "namespace": "stackoverflow.example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Record_1_1",
    "fields": [
      {"name": "value0", "type": "string"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "namespace": "stackoverflow.example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Record_1_2",
    "fields": [
      {"name": "value0", "type": "string"},
      {"name": "value1", "type": "string", "default": "Hello World"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "namespace": "stackoverflow.example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Record_2_1",
    "fields": [
      {"name": "someList", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "int"}}
    ]
  },
  {
    "namespace": "stackoverflow.example.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Record_2_2",
    "fields": [
      {"name": "someBool", "type": "boolean", "default": "false"},
      {"name": "someList", "type": {"type": "array", "items": "int"}}
    ]
  }
]
```

The classes are generated using the following Maven Build-Plugin:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>schema</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
          <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
          <stringType>String</stringType>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This is the code I use to test my evolution:

**AvroTest.java:**

```
package stackoverflow.example;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter;
import stackoverflow.example.avro.Record_1_1;
import stackoverflow.example.avro.Record_1_2;
import stackoverflow.example.avro.Record_2_1;
import stackoverflow.example.avro.Record_2_2;

public class AvroTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        executeTest0();
        executeTest1();
        executeTest2();
    }

    /**
     * Test if read and write methods work
     */
    private static void executeTest0() {
        Record_1_1 source1 = new Record_1_1("A");
        Record_1_1 dest1 = trySerializeDeserialize(source1, Record_1_1.class, Record_1_1.class);
        if (dest1 == null || !Objects.equals(source1.getValue0(), dest1.getValue0())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Record_1_1 Test 0 failed");
        }

        Record_1_2 source2 = new Record_1_2("A", "B");
        Record_1_2 dest2 = trySerializeDeserialize(source2, Record_1_2.class, Record_1_2.class);
        if (dest2 == null || !Objects.equals(source2.getValue0(), dest2.getValue0()) || !Objects.equals(source2.getValue1(), dest2.getValue1())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Record_1_2 Test 0 failed");
        }

        Record_2_1 source3 = new Record_2_1(new ArrayList<>());
        Record_2_1 dest3 = trySerializeDeserialize(source3, Record_2_1.class, Record_2_1.class);
        if (dest3 == null || !Objects.equals(source3.getSomeList(), dest3.getSomeList())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Record_2_1 Test 0 failed");
        }

        Record_2_2 source4 = new Record_2_2(true, new ArrayList<>());
        Record_2_2 dest4 = trySerializeDeserialize(source4, Record_2_2.class, Record_2_2.class);
        if (dest4 == null || !Objects.equals(source4.getSomeBool(), dest4.getSomeBool()) || !Objects.equals(source4.getSomeList(), dest4.getSomeList())) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Record_2_2 Test 0 failed");
        }
    }

    private static void executeTest1() {
        Record_1_1 source1 = new Record_1_1("Test");
        Record_1_2 dest1 = trySerializeDeserialize(source1, Record_1_1.class, Record_1_2.class);
        if (dest1 == null || !Objects.equals(dest1.getValue1(), "Hello World")) {
            System.out.println("adding field with default value failed: " + dest1);
        }

        Record_1_2 source2 = new Record_1_2("Test0", "Test1");
        Record_1_1 dest2 = trySerializeDeserialize(source2, Record_1_2.class, Record_1_1.class);
        if (dest2 == null || !Objects.equals(source2.getValue0(), dest2.getValue0())) {
            System.out.println("removing field failed: " + dest2);
        }
    }

    private static void executeTest2() {
        Record_2_1 source1 = new Record_2_1(new ArrayList<>());
        Record_2_2 dest1 = trySerializeDeserialize(source1, Record_2_1.class, Record_2_2.class);
        if (dest1 == null || !Objects.equals(source1.getSomeList(), dest1.getSomeList())) {
            System.out.println("adding boolean field with default value failed: " + dest1);
        }

        Record_2_2 source2 = new Record_2_2(true, new ArrayList<>());
        Record_2_1 dest2 = trySerializeDeserialize(source2, Record_2_2.class, Record_2_1.class);
        if (dest2 == null || !Objects.equals(source2.getSomeList(), dest2.getSomeList())) {
            System.out.println("removing boolean field failed: " + dest2);
        }
    }

    private static <T, E> E trySerializeDeserialize(T source, Class<T> sourceClass, Class<E> destClass) {
        E result;

        try {
            byte[] bytes = write(source, sourceClass);
            result = read(bytes, destClass);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = null;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static <T> byte[] write(T value, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes;

        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(bos, null);
            DatumWriter<T> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(clazz);
            writer.write(value, encoder);

            encoder.flush();
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    private static <T> T read(byte[] bytes, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null);
        DatumReader<T> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(clazz);

        return reader.read(null, decoder);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
adding field with default value failed: null
adding boolean field with default value failed: null
removing boolean field failed: null
```

According to the docs all of my test should work (adding a field with a default-value or removing a field on receiver-side). But I don't think that the docs were just written for fun so is there maybe some setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the way you're trying to deserialize the data. When using `SpecificDatumReader(Class<T>)` constructor, the reader assumes that both writer's schema and reader's schema are the same.

You can fix this by using `SpecificDatumReader(Schema writer, Schema reader)` instead. For example:

```
private static <T, E> E read(byte[] bytes, Class<T> sourceClass, Class<E> destClass) throws Exception {
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(bytes, null);
    DatumReader<E> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(
            SpecificData.get().getSchema(sourceClass),
            SpecificData.get().getSchema(destClass));

    return reader.read(null, decoder);
}
```

Note the output of `DatumWriter` is not an Avro file, which always contains a schema used to serialize the data in its header, but a single serialized object without a header. If you want to test an Avro file instead, you should use `DataFileWriter` and `DataFileReader`.

---

All of your schema changes are compatible and should work according to [Avro format specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html). The only error you have in the schema is a default value of `someBool` - it should be boolean (`false`) not string (`"false"`).